# Allow CloudFront to access an S3 bucket with an origin access identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have made a static website hosting S3 bucket that is served by CloudFront. I would like to restrict bucket access directly only from CloudFront through Origin Access Identity.

I have tried to update the S3 bucket policy but it's showing an error:

```
Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid principal in policy status code: 400, request id
```

I'm trying to use the following policy:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "default" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.default.id}"
  policy = <<EOF
  {
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.id}"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::$/*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the [aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity documentation] [1](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_origin_access_identity.html#updating-your-bucket-policy) the best way to do this is by generating an IAM policy document
with the [`aws_iam_policy_document` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html) and then attaching that directly.

An example would look something like this:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["${module.names.s3_endpoint_arn_base}/*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.iam_arn}"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:ListBucket"]
    resources = ["${module.names.s3_endpoint_arn_base}"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.iam_arn}"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  # ...
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json}"
}
```

If you really want to hand craft the IAM policy as you are in the question then you just need something like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "default" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.default.id}"
  policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.iam_arn}"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.default.arn}""
    }
  ]
}
EOF 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this.

Comment: Be aware that there will be circle dependency which you can avoid if you use third resource aws_s3_bucket_policy to attach the policy to the bucket.
more here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5612#issuecomment-275912351